# How to prevent application pool stop, on POST requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, application-pool

I have a web api service placed on https sub domain. I used castle Windsor to create all classes (per web request), from controller to domain objects.

I tested all actions on local machine and also using fiddler. everything works fine. And no memory leak was happened. and also we have a mobile programmer which worked with all actions and again every thing was fine.

but after hosting on https, by each request to web api urls, application pool stops.

but the request to authorization works fine. What is wrong with my application? here is my code to Config file:

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config, IAppBuilder app)
    {


        // Web API configuration and services
        var container =Bootstrapper.WireUp();

        ConfigCors(container, config);



        RegisterControllers(container);

        UserManagement.Config.Bootstrapper.WireUp(container);
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new WindsorControllerActivator(container));

        container.Register(Component.For<IDataProtectionProvider>().ImplementedBy<DpapiDataProtectionProvider>()
             .UsingFactoryMethod(x => app.GetDataProtectionProvider()));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.AddFiveLevelsOfMediaType();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "Api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });
    }

    private static void ConfigCors(IWindsorContainer container, HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"); 

        config.EnableCors(cors);
    }
```

Comment: Check the server's event log, the error that killed the pool is probably logged there

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific reason that application pool is stopping. It could be a windows registry error, system error or assembly permission error. The best way to find out why is to go and check event viewer.

From **Administrative Tools** select **Event Viewer**

Alternatively, press Windows Key and type Event Viewer. Once there look into the into Windows Logs and then Application logs. Search for any error (red icon)  or warning (yellow icon) that is related to IIS / ASP.Net or .Net framework. I have attached a sample image from my system  -

[image]

Another Instance -

[image]

** EDIT **:  There is one other possibility since it stopped after enabling https. Check the SSL certificate. The most common reason is using same certificate in multiple sites. Only wild card certificates can be used in multiple site. If the certificate is self signed, delete it and create a new one with * , being the prefix for the certificate name. Then use that one.

Comment: Dear @brainless, I cant see your images, and also I find event viewer , but not finding IIS or .Net logs.

Comment: Dear @brainless-coder ,I found it but I cant Understand error message: Application pool 'api.domain.com(domain)(4.0)(pool)' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

Comment: Dear @brainlessCoder , I found this: Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x52157ba0
Faulting module name: webdav.dll, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x52157c52
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00018f33
Faulting process id: 0x1ed0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2ad91c92f9c59
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\webdav.dll
Report Id: 0bd7b250-1985-11e7-80ba-000c295cf30d
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: ...

Comment: Please check my edit in the answer, it could be a result of SSL cert.

Comment: Dear @brainlessCoder I check my certificate files. Server did not give me files. But in plesk I compared certificate Contents:"Private key (*.key)" and "Certificate (*.crt)" are Completely different,But "CA certificate (*-ca.crt) are same.